# How to get the HTML source for Dynamic rendered partial views in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page where it has 3 partial views in total.Lets name A,B,C.During page load,A and B partial views are loaded. 'A' partial view has a dropdown ,and its on change event ,I need to load the partial view 'C'.Am able to get 'C ',but I also need to get the HTML source for the dynamic 'C' partial view when 'Viewpage source' is viewed.Can any 1 help on this?

Thanks 
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar using the controller name: `@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]`